# Display nested data in a grid inside a window with extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I have a model, a store and a grid (which will be populated with the data in the store). On clicking on a row in the grid, it opens up a window which has a testbox, a panel which intern holds another grid. My data is nested and I'm finding it difficult to pass the values to the grid. Below is my model, store and the components.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    //Model
    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'firstname', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'lastname', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'senority', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'dep', type: 'auto' },
            { name: 'dep_id', type: 'int', mapping: 'dep.dep_id'},
            { name: 'dep_Name', type: 'string', mapping: 'dep.dep_Name'},
            { name: 'hired', type: 'string' }
        ]
    });

    //Store
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        storeId:'employeeStore',
//      fields:['firstname', 'lastname', 'senority', 'dep', 'hired'],
        data:[
            {firstname:"Michael",
                lastname:"Scott", 
                senority:7, 
                dep:[{
                    dep_id: 1000,
                    dep_Name: 'HR'
                }], 
                hired:"01/10/2004"},
            {firstname:"Dwight", 
            lastname:"Schrute", 
            senority:2, 
            dep:[{
                dep_id: 1001,
                dep_Name: 'Sales'
                }], 
            hired:"04/01/2004"}
        ]
    });

    //First grid Panel
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Employee Data',
        id: 'gridID',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
        columns: [
            { text: 'First Name',  dataIndex: 'firstname' },

            {
                header: 'Button',
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                icon : 'test.png',
                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e , record) {
                    rIx=rowIndex;
                    Ext.create('MyWindow',{rIx: rowIndex}).show();
                }

            }

        ],

        width: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    // Window
    Ext.define('MyWindow', {
        extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
        store : Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        title: 'My Window',
        items: [        //testfield
                     {
                        xtype: 'textfield',           
                        id : 'fname',
                        fieldLabel:'Name'
                     },
                     //panel
                     {
                         xtype: 'panel',
                         id: 'wPanel',
                         title: 'Test',
                         height: 400,

                         listeners: {
                             afterrender: function(){//alert("-->");
                                        //grid inside the panel which is in window
                                         var wgrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                                        title: 'Employee Data',
                                        id: 'gridID1',
                                        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
                                        columns: [
                                            { text: 'Department ID', 
                                              dataIndex: 'dep_id' 
                                            },
                                            {
                                                text: 'Department Name',
                                                dataIndex: 'dep_Name'

                                            }

                                        ],

                                        width: 300,
                                        height: 250

                                    });
                                  Ext.getCmp('wPanel').add(wgrid);



                                }
                         }
                     }

                 ],
        listeners: {
                afterrender: function(win){
                //alert("idx= " + win.rIx);
                var r = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore').getAt(win.rIx);
                var firstname = r.get('firstname');
                Ext.getCmp('fname').setValue(firstname);   
                }
        }
        });

});
```

Im trying it with mapping and Im not able to see any data in the grid inside the panel. On clicking on the first row, the text box inside the window should display firstname( which is working fine), and the grid inside the window should display department id and department name of that particular employee alone. First, i tried with `hasMany` and `belongsTo`, but of no luck. Now I'm trying with `mapping`. Pls help....

Comment: Do I have to use the proxy and reader options to achieve this...If so, could anyone pls let me know how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed use hasMany in your mapping.

I've made a fiddle for you with your example, I changed a few stuff arround, it's working now. http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/UehS2/

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    //Model
    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'firstname',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'lastname',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'senority',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'dep'
        }, {
            name: 'hired',
            type: 'string'
        }]
    });

    Ext.define('Department', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'dep_id',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'dep_Name',
            type: 'string'
        }]
    });

    //Store
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        storeId: 'employeeStore',
        //      fields:['firstname', 'lastname', 'senority', 'dep', 'hired'],
        data: [{
            firstname: "Michael",
            lastname: "Scott",
            senority: 7,
            dep: [{
                dep_id: 1000,
                dep_Name: 'HR'
            }],
            hired: "01/10/2004"
        }, {
            firstname: "Dwight",
            lastname: "Schrute",
            senority: 2,
            dep: [{
                dep_id: 1001,
                dep_Name: 'Sales'
            }],
            hired: "04/01/2004"
        }]
    });

    //First grid Panel
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Employee Data',
        id: 'gridID',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
        columns: [{
            text: 'First Name',
            dataIndex: 'firstname'
        },

        {
            header: 'Button',
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            icon: 'test.png',
            handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record) {
                rIx = rowIndex;
                Ext.create('MyWindow', {
                    rIx: rowIndex
                }).show();
            }

        }

        ],

        width: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    // Window
    Ext.define('MyWindow', {
        extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        title: 'My Window',
        items: [ //testfield
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'fname',
            fieldLabel: 'Name'
        },
        //panel
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            id: 'wPanel',
            title: 'Test',
            height: 400,

            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (panel) { //alert("-->");
                    //grid inside the panel which is in window
                    var emplStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore');
                    var win = panel.up('window');
                    var depStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        model: 'Department',
                        data: emplStore.getAt(win.rIx).get('dep')
                    });
                    var wgrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                        title: 'Employee Data',
                        id: 'gridID1',
                        store: depStore,
                        columns: [{
                            text: 'Department ID',
                            dataIndex: 'dep_id'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Department Name',
                            dataIndex: 'dep_Name'

                        }],

                        width: 300,
                        height: 250

                    });
                    Ext.getCmp('wPanel').add(wgrid);
                }
            }
        }

        ],
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (win) {
                //alert("idx= " + win.rIx);
                var r = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore').getAt(win.rIx);
                var firstname = r.get('firstname');
                Ext.getCmp('fname').setValue(firstname);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Note that your code can be optimised a lot, but I focused on your current prob.

Comment: Hi Johan Haest, This is just a sample which I was working on and not the real code. Thanks a lot as this works fine. Could you please clarify a few more things as well..1) The models does not have any explicit hasMany or belongsTo or mappings. Does it mean that this approach is an alternative to those or here too, its used implictly. 2) I could see from the `afterrender listener` of the panel that u had `used panel.up('window');`. Is this used to go up 1 level that is from panel to window or will it go to the window even if it is 2 or 3 levels up.

Comment: 1) Yes it is an alternative method, I personnaly don't use the belongTo or hasMany properties.
2) It can go up multiple levels. So if you say have your panel that is  nested in a few containers it will still go to the window (if window is in the parent chain).